# Python - PyQt5 [PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication 'No Module']

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qapplication

I have been attempting to learn PyQt5 in order to create GUI. 
Pip installed the PyQt5 & the PyQt5.tools yet when I attempt to use it
using Visual Studio Code (while having the Python Extension of VS Code installed) I receive an error.

VS Code detects PyQt5 up to PyQt5.QtWidgets, yet it says no module inside QtWidgets named QApplication can be found.

Import Error of VS Code

[image]

On the contrary when it comes to the error, when I attempt to import QApplication from python.exe, no errors nor problems are presented.

Python.exe 'from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication'

[image]

This leads me into thinking the problem resides at VS Code's doorstep..

Thanks for your time/answers.

Comment: I think yet not certain, I ended up fixing it by using Pycharm, adding integration of PyQt5 and tools, which worked fine. Yet searching across the internet I have noticed similar situations, I'd like to find a solution for using VS Code with PyQt5. If anyone has an idea what could solve it not detecting PyQt5.

Answer (score 2):

1. open the **cmd** from start menu **(Command Prompt)**
2. type `pip install pyqt5`
3. type `pip install pyqt5-stubs`
4. install the integration of PyQt5 from VSCode Marketplace

---

**if is it still not working try uninstalling PyQt5 (`pip uninstall pyqt5`)**
and install it again

Answer (score 0):

1. Search "PYQT Integration" on ur VS Code Extension shop
2. Install it
3. Set the configurations (ur pyqtdesigner path and pyuic etc)

this may help u

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with lots of modules specially pytube . PyQt6 , It was all resolved when I changed my interpreter to python 3.11